# Views: link to an admin page

Tags: views, commerce, uri

I want to print a link in place of a field in case of No Results Behaviour.

The link is to admin/commerce/products/add/, but drupal always add /content/ before my relative address.

I've try different attempts, but so far the only solution I've found is to write the absolute path.

Comment: Do you have any screenshot of what you're trying to attempt ?

Comment: Yes: [link in No Results Behavior](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sxZZ6.png)

Comment: I've tried also with Alias Url, but the View always adds  `/content/` before

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proper relative path your url must start with a `/` at the beginin of your url like this : `/admin/commerce/products/add/`

Comment: It doesn't work, the resulting path becomes `localhost/admin/commerce/products/add/`

Comment: I think you should configure a VHOST

Comment: I've found a workaround, as written in my answer, but I'll follow your advice

Answer (score 0):

You have to start link url with /

Comment: As already commented to the pbonnefoi's answer, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the Path value in the View Page Settings, it was set to `/content/page_name`.

The solution is to set it to `/page_name`